# Error: undefined method `symbolizehash!' for Puppet::Util:Module when using create_resources

Tags: puppet

If I try to use create_resources like shown in http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#createresources:

```
class foobar
{
  $myusers = {
    'nick' => { uid    => '1330',
                group  => allstaff,
                groups => ['developers', 'operations', 'release'], },
    'dan'  => { uid    => '1308',
                group  => allstaff,
                groups => ['developers', 'prosvc', 'release'], }
  }

  create_resources(user, $myusers)
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error: undefined method `symbolizehash!' for Puppet::Util:Module
```

How do I get this working!?

Answer (score 1):

The code that you've presented isn't a direct copy of the code from the source.

```
group  => allstaff,
```

^ that should actually be:

```
gid    => allstaff,
```

The thing is, 'group' isn't a valid parameter of the 'User' resource.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, nevermind; an old module I was using defined #create_resources on it's own..